# Why am i getting this error when try to read my file on R

Tags: r

```
# Removing all Objects from current environment.
rm(list = ls())

# Setting directory
setwd("C:/Users/Ashwin/Desktop") 

# Task 2
RG <- read.csv("Assignment3")
```

> In file(file, "rt") :
> cannot open file 'Assignment3': No such file or directory

Comment: Try with `read.csv("Assignment3.csv")`, i.e. by being explicit about the file extension.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. Try `list.files()` and see if the file is in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

When reading the file you need to provide the correct file name including the extension, the file name is character size sensitive.

You are getting the error because the name is not matching the file in the directory.

Solutions:

1. Add an extension eg. `.csv, .DAT, .txt`
2. Make sure the file is in the path `"C:/Users/Ashwin/Desktop"`
3. MAke sure the file name is correct and the characters are the same size. eg. if file in the drive is `"assignment3` you need to write in R `"assignment3` as well.

You can also use:

`RG <- read.csv(file.choose())`
This way a window will pop up to select your file in the file from the folder.